# ES6 import both all (*) and a specific name in the same statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, import, es6-modules

I have an ES6 module, `mod.mjs`:

```js
export default { f1, f2 };
export function f1() {}
export function f2() {}
```

Which I can import and use like this:

```
import { default as mod, f2 } from "./mod.mjs"
mod.f1();
mod.f2();
f2();
```

**Can I do the same without declaring `default` export inside `mod`** and without de-structuring `*` alias after importing it?

I've tried the following but it gives a syntax error:

```
import { * as mod, f2 } from "./mod.mjs"
mod.f1();
mod.f2();
f2();
```

Basically I want this, but using the `import` statement syntax only, if possible:

```
import * as mod from "./mod.mjs"
const { f2 } = mod;

mod.f1();
mod.f2();
f2();
```

If there is no pure JavaScript solution to that, perhaps, TypeScript has a syntax for something like that?

Comment: It's not possible to combine namespace imports with "normal" imports: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-imports (at the time of this comment at least).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are expecting.
The Best approach you can follow is this:

```
import * as mod from "./mod.js";
import { f2 } from "./mod";
mod.f1();
mod.f2();
f2();
```

Comment: Tks but that's not it. I don't want to import the same module twice, or do de-structuring of `*` import in a separate statement.

Comment: It is an extra statement, but would importing the same module twice have any side-effects?

Comment: @gamliela: No, the module will only be *evaluated* ***once***, so the second time you import the same module it will re-use the same "reference".

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below

```
import mod, { f1, f2 } from "./fun.mjs";

mod.f1();
mod.f2();
f1();
f2();
```

Comment: Tks but this syntax only works if the imported module has `export default { f1, f2 }`, i mentioned that in bold in my question. Many 3rd party modules don't have that.